# Replacing the first character of a file with python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a script, with python 3, that downloads single files from github repositories.
It uses requests, but when it saves to a file it has the format
`b'text'`
I need to get rid of the b (which is always the first character of the line), but I can't just use .replace as that gets rid of all bs.
If anyone has any has any idea as how to replace the first character of the file (b) and are willing to help, thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need to "get rid of b", you need to convert your `bytes` object to a `str` object. See first answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Comment: Your script should be writing data, not Python representations of the data, to the file.

Comment: Use .decode() mthod to convert it into strings. default is "utf-8"

Comment: You forgot to include a [mcve] so we can only guess what you did wrong. But you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You have confused that 'b' for a character. See here [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

To get rid of it, you need to decode it

```
url = "https://projecteuler.net/project/resources/p067_triangle.txt"
content = requests.get(url).content.decode('utf8')
```

Comment: Or let requests do the decoding: `content = requests.get(url).text` - this might be better if the encoding isn't known in advance.